# Is this the right way to uninstall Fedora from a dual-boot system?

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, mbr

I'm using fedora 18 side by side Windows 7 and i want to remove fedora. I'm going to that by deleting the fedora partitions from Windows 7. PS: when i installed in the first place fedora, I didn't overwrite MBR, the GRUB2 is installed in `/boot` partition. So is this method will expose me to problem when the laptop boot into Windows 7 ? ( the object of this is to get a new fresh installation of Fedora ).

Comment: So, when you boot your computer, you see the windows boot loader, not Grub?

Comment: @terdon Yes i see windows boot loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the Windows Boot Loader and not `grub` when turning on your machine then deleting the Linux partition should be fine.

You don't need to do this to get a new install of Fedora though, you can just instal over the old system as long as you format your `/` partition during the install process, you will be fine.